# Glue 2 documents, rename all labels in one of them

Tags: emacs

I need to combine several documents into one. Unfortunately both documents started e.g the equation labeling by `\label{eq:1}`. Is there a neat way to work with both TeX files and are cross references allowed?

Or does one need to rename all labels and refs? Since I'm using emacs the auto replace would probably do this but I'm wondering if there is a more intelligent way instead of renaming everything bruteforce :)

Comment: I would agree that a global editing replace of `eq:` to `eqA:` in one document and `eqB:` in the other document would be easiest.

Comment: For future, you might find it easier to give *descriptive* labels, rather than things such as `eq:1`. For example, you might use `eq:bernoulli` if you're describing a `Bernoulli` equation. This aids code readability, and also might help to avoid clashes like your current situation :)

Comment: I personally prefer to use auto-numbered labels, since this make it easier to identify a particular equation by just looking at the compiled PS/PDF.  In the specific case, I suggest to do a search and replace in the first document for \label{eq: -> \label{eq:1000 and \ref{eq: -> \ref{eq:1000 (or, \eqref if you use that).  Then proceed with a “Renumber simple labels” to get back equation numbered sequentially.

Comment: In addition to what @cmhughes said, descriptive labels negate the need for relabeling if you re-order or add equations somewhere in your document. :)

Comment: I'm using descriptive labels but not every equation is descriptive :) Furthermore, I might use the same descriptive label in both documents. But thanks for your comments, I'll choose the relabeling method :)

Comment: If the equation isn't memorable enough for a name, perhaps `equation*`/`align*` is in order, or `\notag` in `align`?

Comment: I'm trying to label as few equations as possible but inside of proofs I often use equations for intermediate calculations. Thinkint of a name for such equations will also cost time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before to merge the two file, open one in emacs.

Use `M-x replace-regexp RET eq:\([A-Za-z0-9]+\) RET eqA:\1`

It will add a `A` after each `eq`. In this case even if you have the same label for two equations in the final file you'll have no errors.

This supposed that each label you've wrote is constructed as `eq:XX` you can modify the regexp to match other construction.